# Vue2 - Importing Classes, Access and Instantiation

Tags: import, vuejs2

By importing classes at two places do I create 2 different instances?

```js
* content of "MyClass.js"

class MyClass {

  constructor() {}

  isAuthenticated() {}
}

const cls = new MyClass();

export default cls;
--------------------------------
* content of "router.js"

import auth from "./MyClass";

Vue.use(Router)
--------------------------------
content of "./plugins/MyPlugin.js"

import clsInstance from "./MyClass";


export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$auth = clsInstance;
  }
}
--------------------------------
* content of main.js

import myFirstPlugin from "./plugins/MyPlugin.js";

Vue.use(myFirstPlugin);


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if( auth.isAuthenticated() ){}

}
new Vue({
    router
})
--------------------------------
* content of someComponent.vue

  methods: {
    logOut() {
        this.$auth.isAuthenticated()

     }
  }
```

Is "auth.isAuthenticated" inside of "router.beforeEach" in "main.js"
identical
with
this.$auth.isAuthenticated() inside of "logOut" in "someComponent.vue"
or there are actually two different instances of "MyClass"created?

Answer (score 1):

`import` is much the same as `require`. The code in `MyClass.js` will only be run once, creating a single instance of `MyClass`. Both calls to `import` will be pulling in the same instance.

You can confirm this by:

1. Putting some console logging in `MyClass.js`. Note that it only gets run once no matter how many times you import it.
2. Add a property to the object you import in one file (e.g. set `auth.myFlag = true`) and then check whether that flag is also present in the other file (i.e. check `clsInstance.myFlag`). This isn't totally conclusive but it's a pretty good way to verify that it's the same object rather than two separate instances.

If you wanted separate instances you might want to try exporting the class itself so that each file can create its own instance.

From the code you've posted I believe `auth.isAuthenticated()` and `this.$auth.isAuthenticated()` are calling the same method on the same object and (depending on what `isAuthenticated` does) should give the same result.